# Finding the window at a point on screen in java

Tags: java, cross-platform, window, locate

Is there any cross-platform way to figure out which window is at a certain point on the screen?

If there is not, what would be the equivalent function to getWindowAtPoint for linux (X11?) and OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is functionality in Swing to identify the component at a given point.  There is no support in the Java Runtime for inquering about other windows, but the robot-classes can grab screenshots.

What do you need to do?

Comment: I am actually trying to implement the functionality of a macroing program (http://www.kaitnieks.com/scar which uses getWindowAtPoint).  It is not very important, but I was wondering if there would be a way to do it in java.

Comment: If it is a non-java Window you want to work with, you cannot do that with the capabilities of Java 6.  You will need to use a library that talks to the operating system with JNI or JNA.  I do not know of such a library :(